# LaTeX list of figures/list of tables with KOMA-Script additions

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft, tocstyle

I am pretty new to the wonderful world of LaTeX and I need your help.

I want to add the prefix "Abb." to each entry of the list of figures, and the prefix "Tab." to each entry of the list of tables. In addition I want to add a ": " after each number in the lists. I tried the following with KOMA-script but it will not work. It displays just the number and the caption of the figure.

Please check my sample:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4,bibliography=totoc,liststotoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newtocstyle[KOMAlike][leaders]{KOMAlikewithdot}{}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlikewithdot}
\settocfeature[lof]{entryhook}{\noindent Abb.\nobreakspace}% 
\settocfeature[lot]{entryhook}{\noindent Tab.\nobreakspace}% 


\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Abb. }
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tab. }

\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}

\listoffigures
\pagebreak

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Bilder/GMH_Fertigungsprozess_mit_Logo}
    \caption{Fertigungsprozess der GMH}
    \label{fig:GMH_Fertigungsprozess_mit_Logo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: Kick out`tocloft`, it does harm. http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/6141/verzeichnisprafix-in-koma-klassen

Comment: On the other hand: What is the reader expecting in a list of figures? I would be expecting a, well, list of the figures in the document. Suddenly seeing type sock, or type wrench or type milk would confuse me.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,81358.html#81358)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use two different packages to change the TOC or the lists. With a KOMA-Script class I would prefer package `tocstyle` because it is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. But it seems to me that there is no additional package needed.

You can use option

```
listof=totoc,
```

to get TOC entries for the lists,

```
listof=entryprefix,
```

to get prefixes for the list entries,

```
toc=sectionentrywithdots,
```

to get dots between the section entries in TOC and their page numbers.

To rename `\figurename` and `\tablename` use

```
\renewcaptionname{german}{\figurename}{Abb.}
\renewcaptionname{german}{\tablename}{Tab.}
```

and for the `:` after the figure or the table number in the lists

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[lof]{\def\autodot{:}}
\BeforeStartingTOC[lot]{\def\autodot{:}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
    bibliography=totoc,
    listof=totoc,
    listof=entryprefix,
    toc=sectionentrywithdots
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{german}{\figurename}{Abb.}
\renewcaptionname{german}{\tablename}{Tab.}

\BeforeStartingTOC[lof]{\def\autodot{:}}
\BeforeStartingTOC[lot]{\def\autodot{:}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Fertigungsprozess der GMH}
    \label{fig:GMH_Fertigungsprozess_mit_Logo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

BTW do you really want to use `german` instead of `ngerman`?

Comment: Thank your vey much! This works well!
I will search for ne ngerman package and will look up the difference. Thank you for tips. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This method appears not to be working as of 2023. I sincerely recommend Arthur Schiwon's article on this topic: http://www.arthur-schiwon.de/formatierung-von-tabellen-und-abbildungsverzeichnis-mit-latex

Comment: @nerdyllama The MWE in my answer still works. Note, that the KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` loads and uses package `tocbasic`. Therefore it is not recommended to load package `tocloft` with a KOMA-Script class. If you want to load `tocloft` use a standard class.