# Space between en-dash and entry in TOC -- Koma-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

[image]

There is an extraneous, presumably 1-en space between the en-dash and the entry in the table of contents. Is there any way to remove it, so that the space between the `--` and the entry is just one en?

```
\documentclass[%
listof=entryprefix,
toc=sectionentrywithdots
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{FiraSans}

\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{~--~}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
type=remarkbox,%
types=remarkboxes,%
float,% define a floating environment
floattype=4,%
name=Remark,%
counterwithin=chapter,
listname={List of Remarks}]{lor}
\setuptoc{lor}{chapteratlist}


\BeforeStartingTOC[lor]{\def\autodot{~--}}

%like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298089/latex-list-of-figures-list-of-tables-with-koma-script-additions

\begin{document}


\listofremarkboxes 

\chapter{title}

\begin{remarkbox}\centering 
    The same thing should always be typeset in the same way and with the same appearance.
\caption{First Law of Typography}\label{rem:typo1}
\end{remarkbox}


\chapter{title}

\begin{remarkbox}\centering The same thing should always be typeset in the same way and with the same appearance.
    \caption{First Law of Typography}\label{rem:typo2}\end{remarkbox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: which space do you want to change? you have specified `~--~`  so that is a font-specified inter-word space either side of the dash.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the image is quite small. In the "List of Remarks", there is _one_ "extra" space _after_ the en-dash, as if it were `~--~~`. I wanted the spaces to reproduce the caption, wherein the spaces are `~--~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, if you restore `listof=graduated`.

```latex
\documentclass[%
listof=entryprefix,
listof=graduated,
toc=chapterentrywithdots% changed for scrbook
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{FiraSans}

\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{~--~}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
type=remarkbox,%
types=remarkboxes,%
float,% define a floating environment
floattype=4,%
name=Remark,%
counterwithin=chapter,
listname={List of Remarks},
tocentryindent=0pt,% <- added
tocentrydynnumwidth,% <- added
tocentrynumsep=0pt% <- added
]{lor}
\setuptoc{lor}{chapteratlist}

\BeforeStartingTOC[lor]{\def\autodot{~--~}}% changed
%like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298089/latex-list-of-figures-list-of-tables-with-koma-script-additions

\begin{document}
\listofremarkboxes 
\chapter{title}
\begin{remarkbox}\centering 
    The same thing should always be typeset in the same way and with the same appearance.
\caption{First Law of Typography}\label{rem:typo1}
\end{remarkbox}
\chapter{title}
\begin{remarkbox}\centering The same thing should always be typeset in the same way and with the same appearance.
    \caption{First Law of Typography}\label{rem:typo2}\end{remarkbox}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

But note the entry number is set in a box. The width of the box depences on the longest entry number in the list.

So if you add

```latex
\clearpage
\setcounter{remarkbox}{99}
\captionof{remarkbox}{Another remark}
```

and run the code three times, you will get

[image]

Comment: I guess with this style (which is bizarre, but must be followed by many institutions) one is bound eventually to run into those problems.

Comment: One way to make it more palatable would be to change to add `\hfill` in case of large numbers (say, 3 digits): `\BeforeStartingTOC[lor]{\def\autodot{\hfill~--~\hfill}}`.